# whiptail - window resize

Tags: bash, shell, resize, whiptail

I'm using whiptail for a menu based tool. I'm able to set the display for the current window on start with :

```
window=$(stty -a | tr \; \\012 |egrep 'rows|columns' | cut '-d ' -f3)

whiptail --title "Multinode Main Menu" --menu "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" --nocancel  $window 20 

...
```

but the content scrumbles when I resize the window. Is there a way to avoid this when using whiptail ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) wikipedia link,

```
eval `resize`
whiptail ... $LINES $COLUMNS $(( $LINES - 8 )) ...
```

Explanation: 
`resize` command identifies current dimensions (LINES and COLUMNS) of current window and sets two environment variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS`. The `eval` block helps set these two env variables in the shell underwhich `whiptail` command would be running. This way `whiptail` receives `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` variables.

This will help you set right dimensions for your whiptail UI.

Comment: I dont think you understood my question - I'm able to set the right dimensions for my window , but when I resize my putty session, that I'm using to ssh , my screen scrambles . Is there a way to avoid this scramble on maximizing or minimizing my putty session ?